# GZIP Compression is working for css/js but not for html

Tags: .htaccess, magento, gzip

I set up GZIP Compression, it's working for css/js files, but not for html page.

Please help me troubleshoot.

Server have compression enabled, here are info.php stats related to compression:

> ```
> _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]   gzip, deflate
> Stream Wrapper    compress.zlib://
> Stream Filter     zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
> Compiled Version  1.2.3
> Linked Version    1.2.3
> ```

Here are the .htacess part:

> ```
> # Insert filter on all content
> SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
> # Insert filter on selected content types only
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
>
> # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
> BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
>
> # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
> BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
>
> # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
> BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
>
> # Don't compress images
> SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
>
> # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
> Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
> ```

It is compressing css and js. Initially on google page insights test all css, js and page itself were showed as not compressed, now only page itself.
Also here is the [screenshot](https://puu.sh/vLyzE/700cb55ba4.png) from firefox web developers tool.

What can be a problem?
I am using magento ver 1.9 if it makes difference.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody with same question the problem was that hosting provider didn't enable "**zlib.output_compression**"

After enabling it the issue is solved.